# Add http header after creating get Observable Angular

Tags: angular, http

I'm trying to add a new http header to a request, but after creating the http Observable and before subscribing to it.

EX:

```
const subscribable = this.http.get<Config>(this.configUrl, {params, headers});
.....
// Here is it possible to add another header?
```

All the things that I have found is adding a header in an interceptor, but I'm not interested in it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No. Using interceptors is one way, and the [Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) pattern could be another one worth considering.